# Count the number of multi-racial students, binary (1,0), each race has its own column

Tags: sql, oracle, count, binary

I'm looking to count the number of Multi-Racial students in a table. Students who have claimed a certain race, receive a '1' for that respective race. If a student is NOT of a particular race, they receive a '0' for that Race Column. Counting the number of times '1' occurs for a single race is no problem, but how would I count the number of students who have more than one race, or Multi-Racial? Example table below. Thank you for any input!

```
Student_ID            White         Black          Asian         Hispanic

================================================================================== 
     2                  1             1              0              0
     3                  0             1              0              1
     4                  0             1              0              0
     5                  0             0              0              1
     6                  1             0              0              0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tab
WHERE White + Black + Asian + Hispanic > 1; -- assuming only 0/1 are allowed values
```

Comment: If other values are allowed, it could be considered as racism ;-)